# ASP.NET MVC form without HTML Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view-helpers

I write ASP.NET MVC application and I found out for me an interesting thing. When I use in View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

a method Login of class HomeController is called. But if I write this html into View:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Login", "Home")" method="post">
```

(form action is leading to the same action of the same controller) it is Index action called instead. Why?
In both cases the same html below is rendered:

```
<form action="/Home/Login" method="post">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, may be for others - I've bought a html template, not for a small money, but the problem was, the button was out of the form tag. So Index action was executed instead.

Answer (score 3):

nothing is wrong there. all expected behavious. `@Url.Action("Login", "Home")` returns string representation of your the action you write there.

Comment: Yep, there must be some other probelm in my project, in the empty clean project it is working as expected... :/